# Can a Prefab loaded from asssetBundle be passed to Vuforia AnchorBehavior declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

The goal is a two step process in which a Prefab of a Vuforia GroundPlane object is loaded from an AssetBundle, and passed to the AnchorBehavior variable declaration in order to place the gameObject.

And my apologies if as a newcomer to Unity C# i am not as accurate as i would like

Tried various approaches to equate the loaded Prefab to the AnchorBehavior. But because these are two types of objects, errors occur indicating these can't be implicitly equal

The declarations are the following:

```
public PlaneFinderBehaviour plane;
public ContentPositioningBehaviour planeFinder;
public AnchorBehaviour model;
public string nameOfAssetBundle;
public string nameOfObjectToLoad;
```

Idea was to pass the "nameOfObjectToLoad" representing the Prefab and pass it to the "AnchorBehavior" value, then the following method could be used "onClick", when the script is attached to a button.

```
public void create()
{
    planeFinder.AnchorStage = model.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();
}
```

The expectation was that the Prefab would be passed to the AnchorBehavior and instantiate the Prefab "onClick"

Here is the full script from which these snippets were extracted.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class anchorManagerBundles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlaneFinderBehaviour plane;
    public ContentPositioningBehaviour planeFinder;
    public AnchorBehaviour model;
    public string nameOfAssetBundle;
    public string nameOfObjectToLoad;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsset(nameOfAssetBundle, nameOfObjectToLoad));
    } 

    IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles");
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, assetBundleName);

        //Load "nameOfAssetBundle" AssetBundle
        var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath);
        yield return assetBundleCreateRequest;

        AssetBundle assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle;

        //Load the "nameOfOjectToLoad" Asset (Use Texture2D since it's a Texture. Use GameObject if prefab)
        AssetBundleRequest asset = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
        yield return asset;

        //Retrieve the object (Use Texture2D since it's a Texture. Use GameObject if prefab)
        GameObject loadedAsset = asset.asset as GameObject;

        //Do something with the loaded loadedAsset  object (Load to RawImage for example) 
        //model = loadedAsset;
    }
    public void create()
    {
        planeFinder.AnchorStage = model.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();
    }

}
```

Further research exposes my novice skills. The final intent, of "model = loadedAsset;" is that i am attempting to directly convert from one data type to another, which can't be done explicitly. But thus far, my research has not found a means to take the loaded Prefab from the AssetBundle and feed it to the AnchorBehaviour variable.

If anyone has any experience with approaches to this kind of conversion between data types, your guidance is very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
By casting the declaration correctly, the conversion error was eliminated.

`model = (asset.asset as AnchorBehaviour);`

but now i have a the NullReference error, indicating that i have failed to declare the value correctly, in this line

```
    {
        planeFinder.AnchorStage = model.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();
    }
```

And this now is my new dilemma, as i am not sure where i have failed to declare the variable correctly.

**UPDATE**
This error is resolved when the AnchorBehaviour variable is set as private. So, now the script compiles, but fails to produce the intended results. This likely points to a need to change how to load the AssetBundle component as described in the IEnumerator section. The Unity Console prints out the following logging comment

```
There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
```

After all the advice, here is the script to-date, which unfortunately does not place the content from the AssetBundle. More research and testing on my part i can see.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class anchorManagerBundles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlaneFinderBehaviour plane;
    public ContentPositioningBehaviour planeFinder;
    private AnchorBehaviour model;
    public string nameOfAssetBundle;
    public string nameOfObjectToLoad;
    private static bool alreadyLoading;
    private static AssetBundle assetBundle;

    void Start()
    {
        // only load the bundle once
        if (!alreadyLoading)
        {
            // set the flag to make sure this is never done again
            alreadyLoading = true;
            StartCoroutine(LoadAsset(nameOfAssetBundle, nameOfObjectToLoad));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadObjectFromBundle(nameOfObjectToLoad);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles");
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, assetBundleName);

        if (assetBundle == null) 
        { 
            var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath); 
            yield return assetBundleCreateRequest; assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle; 
        }

    private IEnumerator LoadObjectFromBundle(string objectNameToLoad)
    {
        AssetBundleRequest assetRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
        yield return assetRequest;

        GameObject loadedAsset = (GameObject)assetRequest.asset;

        model = loadedAsset.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();
    }

    public void create()
    {
        planeFinder.AnchorStage = model;
    }
}
```

After adding the if statement for the asset, which compiles fine, i continue to have the console alert that the "model" (AnchorBehavior/Anchor Stage) field needs to have a value. So it seems that what the script is either not passing the AssetBundle Object declared in the "nameOfObjectToLoad" field, or what is passing is not matching. So for the same of explanation, i temporarily made the "model" field public and manually populated the field. You will see it identifies the Prefab as being a "AnchorBehavior" object.
[Button Values in Editor - Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puUEA.png)

Here is the full error in the Editor Console when attempting to place the object.

```
There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:CreateAnchorAndPlaceContent(Func`2, Vector3, Quaternion)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:PositionContentAtPlaneAnchor(HitTestResult)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(HitTestResult)
Vuforia.PlaneFinderBehaviour:PerformHitTest(Vector2)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(Vector2)
Vuforia.AnchorInputListenerBehaviour:Update()
```

In an effort to further debug the issue, i ammended the following section to this.

```
        if (assetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Load assetBundle!!");
            yield break;
        }
```

The intent was to an attempt to identify if the AssetBundle was in fact being loaded. This was very useful, but it produced a very odd result for which i would solicit advise.

This script is attached to a series of buttons so that when the button is clicked, the create() function is used to instantiate the Prefab based on the variables.

These buttons are grouped on 3 different UI panels. The user clicks on the selected Panel button to expose the desire button panel.

What is very strange is that when the user clicks on the Panel Selection Button, the following errors are placed in the Editor Log. This is before the actual button which has the attached script has been clicked.

On Panel Button Click

```
Failed to Load assetBundle!!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadAsset>d__8:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/anchorManagerBundles.cs:38)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
anchorManagerBundles:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/anchorManagerBundles.cs:23)
```

On Button Click (script attached button)

```
There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:CreateAnchorAndPlaceContent(Func`2, Vector3, Quaternion)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:PositionContentAtPlaneAnchor(HitTestResult)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(HitTestResult)
Vuforia.PlaneFinderBehaviour:PerformHitTest(Vector2)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(Vector2)
Vuforia.AnchorInputListenerBehaviour:Update()
```

I do not understand why the script is being called upon click of Panel Button, which does not have the script attached.

Any advise is most appreciated on this puzzling issue.

Comment: Could you extend your code snippets a bit with more context .. it is hard to understand what you are trying to do from the little code you have provided here

Comment: Hi @derHugo More than glad to do so, i will update the original post with the full script, which is not particularly long. thanks for the inquiry. I am new to StackOverflow and didn't know if that would be acceptable.

Comment: Hi @derHugo, been working hard at solving this issue myself, and have made some progress. If you have any further advise/insights, they are most welcomed.

Comment: I guess the issue is still in `model = (asset.asset as AnchorBehaviour);` you should try `model = (asset.asset as GameObject).GetComponent<AnchorBehavior>();` and later only use `planeFinder.AnchorStage = model;`

Comment: @derHugo, thank you very much for this guidance. I am anxious to put this through its paces, which unfortunately, won't be until this evening. Again, i am most appreciative.

Comment: @derHugo, a HUGE thanks to you for this guidance. This allowed my code to perform as originally intended. And as i looked over your guidance, i realize that my mistake was that i should have been equating model to the AnchorBehaviour inside of the IEnumerator before i called it in the "create()" method.

Comment: @derHugo, Just as a point of followup. As i have reported, your solution did work. Interesting though, when i proceeded to add this script to a series of buttons that upon click, execute the final "create()" function, the "no content to place" error returned. I am wondering if it has to do with how i am now structuring the AssetBundles.

Comment: @derHugo, continuing comments, When i ran the tests using your excellent guidance, the bundle contained 3 prefabs. But with that structure if i clicked the second button the errors indicated that it couldn't load the Bundle the second time. So, i restructured each bundle to contain a single Prefab. And this may be the source of the current issue. I will investigate, as i am so very close to how best to execute this important functionality.

Comment: @derHugo, in the interest of discovery, i created the iOS build and successfully installed. Then enabled Debugging so that i could trace the script in action, but do not identify any particular issues. That said, i am new to using the debugging Unity, so i may well be missing something. Mostly i wanted to report on my ongoing efforts.

Comment: Hello @derHugo If you review my latest efforts to debug the issue, you will see i uncovered a peculiar behavior. The script seems to be executing on any button click, even on buttons that do not have the script attached. Any insight or advise is most appreciated.

Comment: Hi, currently your question is getting broarder and broarder going further away from the original issue. You should tackle one issue at a time. Of there are other questions coming up then rather open a new one instead of extending your original post more and more.

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, i will encapsulate this into a new question. I am relatively new to Stackoverflow and was wondering how best to ask extended questions like this. I will post a newly framed question this is more specific to the current issue. Again, thanks for your valuable guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [`AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync.html)

> Prior to version 5.0, users could fetch individual components directly using LoadAsync. This is not supported anymore. Instead, please use LoadAssetAsync to load the game object first and then look up the component on the object.

---

You can't simply typecast the retrieved `GameObject` reference to a `AnchorBehaviour` reference. Instead you have to use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html).

---

So what you should do is

```
AssetBundleRequest assetRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
yield return assetRequest;

GameObject loadedAsset = (GameObject)assetRequest.asset;

// since model is already of type AnchorBehaviour
// you should do the GetComponent already here
model = loadedAsset.GetComponent<AnchorBehavior>();
```

Now that you already have a reference of type `AnchorBehaviour` the second `GetComponent` call would be redundant since it returns the same reference. So now only use

```
public void create()
{
    planeFinder.AnchorStage = model;
}
```

---

In case you have multiple instances of this script it might make sense to load the assetBundle only once like

```
private static bool alreadyLoading;
private static AssetBundle assetBundle;

void Start()
{
    // only load the bundle once
    if(!alreadyLoading) 
    {
        // set the flag to make sure this is never done again
        alreadyLoading = true;
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsset(nameOfAssetBundle, nameOfObjectToLoad));
    }
    else
    {
        LoadObjectFromBundle(nameOfOjectToLoad);
    }
} 

private IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles");
    filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, assetBundleName);

    var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath);
    yield return assetBundleCreateRequest;

    assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle;

    LoadObjectFromBundle(objectNameToLoad);
}

private IEnumerator LoadObjectFromBundle(string objectNameToLoad)
{
    AssetBundleRequest assetRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
    yield return assetRequest;

    GameObject loadedAsset = (GameObject)assetRequest.asset;

    model = loadedAsset.GetComponent<AnchorBehavior>();
}
```

Comment: Hello @derHugo. This script works well. But one follow on question that may speak to my relative newness to Unity C#. It is unclear to me if i can attach this script to multiple buttons to execute the loading of the AssetBundle object. Online research seems to suggest that multiple instances of the same coroutine running could be problematic, and may well be why the first object loads, and then following button clicks return the No Content error. Any insight is most appreciated.

Comment: I honestly never used AssetBundles before. Having the same script with Coroutines on multiple instances is no problem .. those Coroutines are not "concurrent" since they are running on different instances. However, I don't know how AssetBundles work if you try to load the same file multiple times ... issue might be there.

Comment: I would suggest to make the `assetBundle` variable a `static` field so it is shared between all instances of that script and only load it once like `if(assetBundle == null) {var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath); yield return assetBundleCreateRequest; assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle;}`

Comment: thank you so much. I have learned so much from you, i feel like my Unity C# skills are advancing. Once again this makes sense. I will implement a test this evening and keep you informed of the progress.

Comment: Hello Again @derHugo, following your excellent guidance, the updated script indeed compiles fine (though there are some VisualStudio alerts which don't prevent compiling. Unfortunately, when run, nothing is placed, "There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place". I have placed the full, current script in my original question for your review. You have gone the extra mile, i do NOT expect you to continue. I am very appreciative of your help thus far. Ah, listening to a novice must be hard!

Comment: Is it possible that `model` still is `null`? Happens if there is no `AnchorBehaviour` attached to the loaded GameObject

Comment: You are very kind @derHugo, the script is attached to each button to execute. I will double check, but i believe that i have preconfigured the field for model to reflect the object in the AssetBundle. For example the Bundle to be loaded might be named "categoryone", and the prefab in the bundle "groundplanemid". I realize that i have not implemented the null check that you allded to in your comments. Have to figure that out as well. I will double check all the buttons and let you know. Again, i am extremely appreciative.

Comment: following your suggestion i updated the script to include the null check on the assetbundle, and the script compiles just fine. But the failure to load the object continues. I updated my post to reflect the updated script, and, as i explain, included a screenshot of the desired outcome. (i temporarily made the AnchorBehavior field public so i could show the desired outcome. Either the object isn't being passed, or what is passed isn't read as an "anchor behavior" object. I remain very appreciative of your engagement.

Comment: unfortunately i have come to the end of my knowledge on how to accomplish this. If you have any reference sites to which you can direct me to unravel this issue i would be very appreciative of that information. You have helped me get quite far, and i suspect there is just a small leap left, but it is beyond my skills i am ashamed to admit.

Comment: Thanks again @derHugo, Here is more error detail for you. -- "There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:CreateAnchorAndPlaceContent(Func`2, Vector3, Quaternion)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:PositionContentAtPlaneAnchor(HitTestResult)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(HitTestResult)
Vuforia.PlaneFinderBehaviour:PerformHitTest(Vector2)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(Vector2)
Vuforia.AnchorInputListenerBehaviour:Update()"

Comment: This script has been working wonderfully @derHugo. A new wrinkle has arisen in which there is a need on some of the loaded asset bundles, to remove them from the device after the asset is loaded. This is sort of a "one time use" idea. I am wondering how one would do this. There doesn't seem to be a delete function in the AssetBundle API. I have seen examples using the "if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName"))
                        File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName");", but that obviously doesn't work in this script. Thoughts?

Comment: @muckletone well the thing is that we here loaded assets from the `StreamingAssets` folder ... this folder is compressed into the resulting apppackage ... you can't modify this package afterwards. The code you posted would work if you loaded an asset from the "outside" ... e.g. the `persistentDataPath` which is read/write in a build

Comment: thanks much for the reply. This is good to know. Sounds like this alternative method wouldn't work in my case, as we are loading these onto the iOS devise. I will go back to the drawing board and come up with a different approach. Again, thanks so much for the response.

Comment: Before i proceeded, i wanted to get your advice. There is a related question which you spoke into, and it is almost a match to the question i was trying to formulate. It is related to a question posted by user "Seoner", question number, "58285679". I was thinking of commenting here to that user to ask if their approach would work for AssetBundles that are used in the Vuforia AR context of Unity. What you guided me through in this thread was very successful, and now being able to alter the materials of these placed assets is my next step. Your advise is most appreciated