# Why does Unity C# Coroutine execute upon click of an unrelated button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

The script is part of a Unity/Vuforia AR app in which the user is able to place various PreFab models via the Vuforia ground detection system. These Prefabs are loaded into AssetBundles in order to manage memory overhead.

The script to accomplish this is executing prematurely.

This Coroutine script is attached to each button. Upon "onClick" the script is intended to load an AssetBundle containing a Prefab, and then instantiate the loaded Prefab object into the AR world.
The problem currently is that the script is executing upon the click on a UI panel opening button, which enables access to the actual placement UI buttons to which the script has been attached.

I arrived at this script the excellent via input from @derHugo. That thread can be found here: [Can a Prefab loaded from asssetBundle be passed to Vuforia AnchorBehavior declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368753/can-a-prefab-loaded-from-asssetbundle-be-passed-to-vuforia-anchorbehavior-declar)

Here is the script that is attached to the placement buttons

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class anchorManagerBundles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlaneFinderBehaviour plane;
    public ContentPositioningBehaviour planeFinder;
    private AnchorBehaviour model;
    public string nameOfAssetBundle;
    public string nameOfObjectToLoad;
    private static bool alreadyLoading;
    private static AssetBundle assetBundle;

    void Start()
    {
        // only load the bundle once
        if (!alreadyLoading)
        {
            // set the flag to make sure this is never done again
            alreadyLoading = true;
            StartCoroutine(LoadAsset(nameOfAssetBundle, nameOfObjectToLoad));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadObjectFromBundle(nameOfObjectToLoad);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles");
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, assetBundleName);

        if (assetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Load assetBundle!!");
            yield break;
        }

        { 
            var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath); 
            yield return assetBundleCreateRequest; assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle; 
        }

    private IEnumerator LoadObjectFromBundle(string objectNameToLoad)
    {
        AssetBundleRequest assetRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
        yield return assetRequest;

        GameObject loadedAsset = (GameObject)assetRequest.asset;

        model = loadedAsset.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();
    }

    public void create()
    {
        planeFinder.AnchorStage = model;
    }
}
```

The desired/expected result was that upon clicking the UI button, the selected AssetBundle is loaded and the named PreFab is loaded for placement into the AR world upon tapping the screen.

I added a debug break in order to identify if the Asset Bundle is successfully loaded. The error below is then registered when the unrelated UI panel opening button is pressed, which does not have the script attached, indicating that the script is running prematurely.

```
Failed to Load assetBundle!!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadAsset>d__8:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/anchorManagerBundles.cs:38)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
anchorManagerBundles:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/anchorManagerBundles.cs:23)
```

Then i proceed to the actual placement button, of course the there is no prefab placed because of the premature execution.

```
There is no content to place at the anchor. Set the "Anchor Stage" field to the content you wish to place.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:CreateAnchorAndPlaceContent(Func`2, Vector3, Quaternion)
Vuforia.ContentPositioningBehaviour:PositionContentAtPlaneAnchor(HitTestResult)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(HitTestResult)
Vuforia.PlaneFinderBehaviour:PerformHitTest(Vector2)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(Vector2)
Vuforia.AnchorInputListenerBehaviour:Update()
```

The question is why does this script execute prematurely, and thus thwarting the loading of the asset bundle and its selected PreFab

Comment: but the `LoadAsset` routine is started in `Start` .. at this moment `assetBundle` will most probably still be `null` => error message. Has nothing to do with your other button ... maybe when using the other button this object is spawned/enabled/scene switched or something else like that that causes the `Start` to be called?

Comment: Thanks @derHugo. The button that i was alluding to is enabling the panel on which the scripted buttons are attached, that may be what causes Start to be called. This evening i may see if this script will behave differently if i place the routine in Update. I will also test by placing a test button on the primary UI where no pre-actions are required and test from there. Again, thanks.

Comment: Note that I think you messed up the methods a bit .. in `LoadAsset` you are checking for `assetBundle` but it will **never** be set! It's kind of like you would say: If it is not loaded yet then do **not** load it -> makes no sense

Comment: Hello @derHugo. changing the routine to Update() didn't make any difference, which i didn't really expect. And additionally, if the selection buttons are moved off of the secondary panel, then that debug break is never hit, though the error that there is nothing to place persists. As regards the methods, i am confused as to why the LoadAsset Parameters in the coroutine are not referenced in the methods. I must confess i have reached the end of my novice abilities. I will continue to work on this unexpected behavior. Maybe time to redesign. Thank you VERY much for your continuing interest.

Comment: go bak and have a look at the previous code we had in your old question (or well .. my answer) ;) your newly added `if(assetBundle == null)` makes no sense at this point .. you might to move it to the end of the `LoadAsset` routine .. currently your assetBundle is never even tried to be loaded ;)

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, yes, that makes sense. I will do exactly that and report the findings. You are right, i have bungled the sequence of the routines. I am very appreciative of the guidance. Hopefully good news to report.

Comment: Last comment for the night @deHugo, moving the 'if(assetBundle == null)' is moved to the end of the LoadAsset routine, a new error is shown in the console. `Assets/Scripts/anchorManagerBundles.cs(46,13): error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'assetBundleCreateRequest' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"` and will not compile. Picking it up again tomorrow. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact you have a `{` too much there

---

your check for

```
if (assetBundle == null)
```

makes no sense at this point .. it will always be `null` so you tell your routine "If the assetBundle was not loaded yet .. then please do not load it".

---

You should move the check to the end. I personally would then invert the check you had in order to skip the loading if it **was** loaded already.

Note: You also missed the last line

```
LoadObjectFromBundle(objectNameToLoad);
```

at the end of `LoadAsset` so the object is never loaded for the first instance calling `LoadAsset`. For the others it actually makes no sense to call `LoadObjectFromBundle` in `Start` (sorry my bad for not noticing it the first time). The coroutine is not done yet but they will try to load an object from an `assetBundle` which wasn't set yet.

So I would change it to

```
private IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
{
    // can be done in one single call
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles", assetBundleName);

    // if at this point the assetBundle is already set we can skip the loading
    // and directly continue to load the specific object
    if (!assetBundle)
    {
        var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath);
        yield return assetBundleCreateRequest;

        assetBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle;

        if (!assetBundle)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed! assetBundle could not be loaded!", this);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("assetBundle is already loaded! Skipping", this);
    }

    // YOU ALSO MISSED THIS!!
    yield return LoadObjectFromBundle(objectNameToLoad);
}

private IEnumerator LoadObjectFromBundle(string objectNameToLoad)
{
    // This time we wait until the assetBundle is actually set to a valid value
    // you could simply use
    //yield return new WaitUntil(() => assetBundle != null);
    // but just to see what happens I would let them report in certain intervals like
    var timer = 0f;
    while (!assetBundle)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer > 3)
        {
            timer = 0;
            Debug.Log("Still waiting for assetBundle ...", this);
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    var assetRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(objectNameToLoad);
    yield return assetRequest;

    var loadedAsset = (GameObject)assetRequest.asset;

    model = loadedAsset.GetComponent<AnchorBehaviour>();

    // add a final check
    if(!model)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to load object from assetBundle!", this);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully loaded model!", this);
    }
}

// and now make sure you can't click before model is actually set
public void create()
{
    if(!model)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("model is not loaded yet ...", this);
        return;
    }

    planeFinder.AnchorStage = model;
}
```

Comment: tremendous thanks here @derHugo. The logic you are laying out here makes a lot sense once i see it expressed in code with good commentary, which is what helps me as a relative newcomer to Unity C#. I will be testing this evening and will report the outcome, with great confidence it is the solution.

Comment: the good news is that these adjustments work well, with a caveat. The bundle and object are loaded. What is happening is related to the scripts execution function "Start()". Soon as the panel is enabled, which by default enables all the buttons, the script on all the buttons execute the "Start() execution. And of course, nothing will be loaded properly. So, the good news is that i think the script works well (tested on a single button). Next i will investigate if i can use the coroutine "WaitUntil" call to not run until the "onClick". HUGE thanks.

Comment: One last thing, @derHugo, i understand that a coroutine doesn't interrupt the app's main thread, so the WaitUntil is unlikely to help. I am investigating the use of the "invoke" method, though my reading suggests that is a less than desirable approach.

Comment: What do you mean? Coroutines still are executed inn he main thread.. it's kind of a temporary `Update` method. `yield` allows to render the frame and continue the `IEnumerator` in the next frame. Therefore `WaitUntil` doesn't "block" anything it just returns as long as the asset isnt loaded yet

Comment: My apologies @derHugo, you are obviously correct, i didn't explain myself well. Currently, soon as the scene loads, any active button with this script attached begins to execute. What i was poorly explaining was to say i am exploring how to have the coroutine wait to execute upon the "onClick". Otherwise, in the final app, which has many buttons with this script, they are all beginning the routine, at which things break down and nothing is loaded. Again my apologies for the poor communication.

Comment: Hi @derHugo. Ran a simple experiment. I created button to enable the button with the script attached. Soon as the coroutine button is enabled, the Bundle is loaded and i can place the object. Clicking that button also deactives the button. Extended the test with 2 more button sets as described. The result was once the first coroutine ran, further buttons retain the first loaded bundle/prefab. So i extend the test by adding a "stopAllCoroutines()" with onClick. But this made no difference. It is my novice assumption here that the coroutine is persistent and blocks other actions. Your thoughts?

Comment: For anyone, including @derHugo, i wanted to update that that this script clearly works well. After many tests and attempts to use the same script on multiple buttons to load different AssetBundles and Prefabs it will only load parameters of the first activated button. As a result, currently the only solution i can see viable is to create a uniquely named duplicate script attached to each button. Using that approach works correctly. What is unclear is if that is a good "Best Practice". Comments and/or advise is most welcome.